# can't go beyond Berkshire Hathaway while getting data of all SP500 companies

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to get beyond berkshire Hathaway while getting data of all SP500 companies using the pandas_datareader library.

This is the code:

```
    import bs4 as bs
import pickle 
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import requests 

def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "1xml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        mapping = str.maketrans('.', '-')
        ticker = ticker.translate(mapping)
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(tickers, f)

    print(tickers)

    return tickers

#save_sp500_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500 = False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)

    for ticker in tickers:
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))

        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

get_data_from_yahoo()
```

And yes, I am taking the course from pythonprogramming.net 
any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia page has "." as the empty character in symbols while Yahoo has "-". 
Replacing the character would be sufficient:

```
df = web.DataReader(ticker.replace('.','-'), 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Edit:
Your code is fine, I tested it and it works. As I executed it, it got 'BRK-B' as is intended while yours goes for 'BRK.B' that obviously doesn't exist. I don't know why you had "1xml" in there when it's supposed to be "lxml".

Comment: Didn't work. Still getting the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: My answer is actually wrong, the replacement is already done with str.maketrans in save_sp500_tickers. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: This is the error that i'm getting : Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BRK.B&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=11&e=31&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv